# C++ why does my array not pop into my stack?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I created an array for studentrecords and am supposed to pop it into my stack.. well everything works except for my stack.pops and stack.pushes in MAIN...I am so close to finishing this program I am wondering if anyone knows any solutions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Studentrecords
{
private:
    struct student
    {
        string name;
        string address;
        int ID;
        double gpa;
    };

    student *stackArray;
    int stackSize;
    int top;

public:
    Studentrecords();
    Studentrecords(int size);
    ~Studentrecords();
    void push(string name, string address, int id, double gpa);
    void pop();
    bool isFull() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void display();
};

Studentrecords::Studentrecords(int size)
{
    stackArray = new student[size];
    top = -1;
}

Studentrecords::Studentrecords()
{
    stackSize = 20;
    stackArray = new student[stackSize];
    top = -1;
}

Studentrecords::~Studentrecords()
{
    delete [] stackArray;
}

void Studentrecords::push (string name, string address, int id, double gpa)
{
    if (isFull())
    {
        cout << "The stack is full!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        student newStudent;
        newStudent.name = name;
        newStudent.address= address;
        newStudent.ID = id;
        newStudent.gpa = gpa;
        stackArray[top] = newStudent;
        top++;
    }
}

void Studentrecords::pop ()
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "The stack is empty!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << stackArray[top-1].name << endl;
        cout << stackArray[top-1].address << endl;
        cout << stackArray[top-1].ID << endl;
        cout << stackArray[top-1].gpa << endl;
        top--;
    }
}

bool Studentrecords::isFull() const
{
    bool status;
    if (top == stackSize - 1)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
}

bool Studentrecords::isEmpty() const
{
    bool status;
    if (top == -1)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
}

void Studentrecords::display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i< top; i++)
    {
        cout << stackArray[i].name << endl;
        cout << stackArray[i].address << endl;
        cout << stackArray[i].ID << endl;
        cout << stackArray[i].gpa << endl << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int catchVar;

    Studentrecords stack();

    cout << "Pushing 1st";
    stack.push("Jonny", "123 ave", 2343, 3.2);

    cout << "pushing 2nd";
    stack.push("Robby", "123 ave", 2343, 3.2);

    cout << "Popping ";
    stack.pop(catchVar);
    cout << catchVar << endl;

    cout << "Popping ";
    stack.pop(catchVar);
    cout << catchVar << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this code even compile? You're calling `pop(catchVar)` but `pop()` takes no parameters.

Comment: @GregHewgill no, it couldn't possibly compile.

Comment: you might want to work on your indention and reduce the code to the relevant parts. You might also want to mention what exactly the problems are. It's not really fun to wade through less then desiarable indented code without knowing what one is looking for...

Comment: You kind of forgot to tell us what the problem is. Just telling us that something doesn't work isn't very helpful. Think about it like going to a mechanic -- would you just say "my car doesn't work"? Or would you tell him what precisely you were doing and what precisely went wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Studentrecords stack();
```

Does not declare a `Studentrecords` named `stack`, it declares a function named `stack` that returns a `Studentrecords`. Change it to

```
Studentrecords stack;
```

Also your class needs at least a copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Incidentally, `clang++` provides a very clear warning for this most vexing parse. It's a shame GCC doesn't.

Comment: Or `Studentrecords stack{};` if you have a C++11 compiler

Comment: @Prætorian that's unnecessary though, so best to just leave them off.

Comment: In this case, it is. But what if `Studentrecords` was a POD?

Comment: @KevinBallard unfortunately most people learning C++ do so at a university on a very old compiler or using Windows at home, they don't have a chance to use clang.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the compiler's error?
Or the produced output VS the expected output?
Without that, I'll have to say that your pop function doesn't take arguments and you are passing it catchVar... that would be a compiler error.